# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a compact operator $T: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$, then $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{\ast}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I tried to manipulate the kernel of $T - \lambda$ and tried to manipulate inner products of things. But still don't know how to use ``compactness" of $T$ to prove this fact.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Remark that if $\lambda$ is a non zero  element of the spectrum of $T$ it is equivalent to $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, and it is equivalent to $T-\lambda$ is not invertible which is equivalent to $(T-\lambda)^*=T^*-\bar\lambda$ is not invertible, we deduce that $\bar\lambda$ is an element of the spectrum of $T^*$ thus $\bar\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*$ since $T^*$ is also compact.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators

Comment: This might not be true if $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: It is not true for $\lambda=0$. Take a weighted shift $Te_k=\lambda_ke_{k+1},\ k\in\mathbb N$ with $\lambda_k\to 0$. Then for $T^*$ you have an eigenvalue $0$, but not for $T$.